# Did something happen to the login process on SO, possibly just for claim id accounts?

Tags: support, user-accounts

Did something change in Stack Overflow's login logic or this is my (or claimid.com's) problem?

When I try to log in with my claim id account, SO says that the account is new. My URL in Chrome (from an old session) is different than the one I'm seeing in Firefox.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, claimid changed their syntax

from

http://claimid.com/yourname

to

http://openid.claimid.com/yourname

email us via the link at the bottom of every page to fix.

Comment: Whats worse is that both formats still work.