# ClaimID login fails on ServerFault?

Tags: support, status-completed, openid, login

Does **ClaimID** changed syntax [again](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11558/claimid-accounts)?

This morning I cannot login using my ClaimID openID account on **ServerFault**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We're looking at this now.

edit: this was a configuration error on our end and is now fixed.

Comment: thank you, lightning fast as usual :D

Comment: I have a problem with my own OpenID which delegates authentication to Myopend.com. Jeff could you please check it as well? My account is http://stackoverflow.com/users/55209/artem-k

The error returned is “Unable to log in with your OpenID provider: No OpenID endpoint found.”